# Proof for LTI Systems

Tags: convolution, linear-systems, impulse-response

Suppose we have a system $S$.If I know   the impulse response $h(t)$ I can predict the output for any input $x(t)$ if a system is linear and time invariant.However how do we prove that statement?

Comment: Hint: What is the output of an LTI system when the input is a shifted impulse?